# myNames gets the list but when trying to get the average, an error saying object is not iterable in the for loop when trying to get the average

Tags: python-3.x

```
def myNames():

    b = []
    while True:
    a = input("whats the name: ")
    if a != "done":
     b.append(a)
    elif a == "done":
     break

return b

x = myNames()
print (x)

def getAverageLength(myNames):
 total = 0
 for i in myNames: #This line of code gives me an error and I cant figure it out
   total = total + len(i) 
   average = float(total) / float(len(myNames))
   return average

getAverageLength(myNames)
```

It takes my first function (myNames) as an argument. Ive been trying to figure this error out but have no idea what to do here

Comment: you call `getAverageLength` with `myNames` (functions name) but i think it would make sense to call it with `x` 

Answer (score 0):

Your last line: `getAverageLength(myNames)`, like you said in your description, is using `myNames` as a parameter which is only present as a function in the current scope.

This means when you reach your `for` loop, you end up trying to iterate over a function, since that is what was passed into `getAverageLength`

Maybe you meant `getAverageLength(x)`?
Or perhaps `getAverageLength(myNames())` since `myNames()` passes the result of the function as opposed to the function itself.

To correctly calculate the average length  of the strings, you could use the following:

```
averageLength = sum(map(len, x)) / len(x)
```

Comment: I want to get the average length of the names from def myNames() by using the def getAverageLength. How would I go about this?

Comment: @Yokoe please see revised answer